# Should iPad 3 Retina images be 4x resolution?

Tags: image, ipad, resolution

I've been slicing images from a PSD for an app and the design team is saying that the slices look fuzzy on ipad.

The design I'm slicing from is 2048 by 1536.  The team says I need to double the size of the resources when saving.  This would size them relative to a 4096 x 3072 pixel PSD.

That's @4x screen resolution.

Does' iPad3 really support @4x resolution?  I thought retina was only 2x...

Comment: It's 4 times the resolution, but you achieve it by doubling the size in each direction. `2048 x 1536` is the resolution of an iPad 3's display. If stuff looks blurry, then you are perhaps using JPEG images (or some other kind of lossy compression) instead of PNG ones.

Comment: they are png's -- i think something else is going wrong.. now i just need to convince them that doubling the size of all the resources to work at 4096x3072 won't fix it